# Cannot include livewire component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I've created a default livewire component and called it `\app\Http\Livewire\kandidaatList.php`. In my `resources\views\admin\kandidaat\index.blade.php` I include it:

`<livewire:kandidaatList />`

Finally in my `resources\views\layouts\head.blade.php` I include `@livewireStyles` in the `<head>` and in my `resources\views\layouts\footer.blade.php` include `@livewireScripts` So everything should be setup correctly.

But if I go to the page I get an error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
> file_put_contents(/var/www/bootstrap/cache/livewire-components.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied (View: /var/www/resources/views/admin/kandidaat/index.blade.php)

Without the livewire include I can open the page.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue with your local Laravel development environment more than Livewire. Can you verify, if your `bootstrap` directory:

- exists,
- is writable for Laravel / your web-server user (e.g. nginx). Usually that user is called `www-data`.

Do you use dockerized development environment such as Sail or Laradock?

Comment: > `root@21ed541a9249:/var/www/bootstrap/cache# ls -l livewire-components.php`
> `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 83 May 20 07:07 livewire-components.php`

The file does exist and we're using Laradock.

Comment: How are you running laradock, as `root` or regular user?

Comment: Myea just blasted the files in the cache folder to 777.

Comment: Yeah, one way to do it. I've got 755 with my user (under which I run docker / Laravel Sail too)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error on my server after deploying an upgrade to Livewire and a new form arrangement that included some components.
After the following, I was able to load the page:

```
sudo rm -rf storage/framework/sessions/*
sudo rm -rf storage/framework/views/*
sudo php artisan cache:clear
sudo php artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data public/uploads/
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data public/temp/
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage/uploads
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage/tmp
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Some of those folders were not present on my disk so I made them and ran the chown directives again.